# Stata - How to manipulate data and create observations

Tags: row, stata

I have a tricky question about how to manipulate some data.  Suppose I have the following structure of data:

```
_n   group   attr     value
1      1     height     3
2      1     weight     12
3      1     length     9  
4      2     weight     15
5      3     height     4
```

I want to have all groups have `height`, `weight`, and `length`.  If there is initially not a value, I want to have a missing value be put in.  Thus the end result would look like this:

```
_n   group   attr     value
1      1     height     3
2      1     weight     12
3      1     length     9 
4      2     height     .
5      2     weight     15
6      2     length     .  
7      3     height     4
8      3     weight     .
9      3     length     .
```

I don't know how to do this, but perhaps it would involve `reshape`?

Another thing I thought about would be to use `egen` to sum by group.  We could figure out that group 1 has 3 members, group 2 has 1 member, and group 3 has 1 member.  Then we could perform functions on groups 2 and 3 to get them up to par.  But this could get complicated.

Comment: Reminder: Good questions here usually show attempts at code, not just wild guesses at what might be relevant. Your question is clear and specific, so it gets through the frontier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (1) very easy and (2) usually the wrong way to go.

(1) `fillin` is dedicated to this task. Your example leaves ambiguous whether `attr` is a numeric variable with value labels or a string variable, but this works either way:

```
. clear 

. input   group  str6 attr     value

          group       attr      value
1. 1     "height"     3
2. 1     "weight"     12
3. 1     "length"     9  
4. 2     "weight"     15
5. 3     "height"     4
6. end 

. fillin group attr 

. list, sepby(group) 

      +----------------------------------+
      | group     attr   value   _fillin |
      |----------------------------------|
   1. |     1   height       3         0 |
   2. |     1   length       9         0 |
   3. |     1   weight      12         0 |
      |----------------------------------|
   4. |     2   height       .         1 |
   5. |     2   length       .         1 |
   6. |     2   weight      15         0 |
      |----------------------------------|
   7. |     3   height       4         0 |  
   8. |     3   length       .         1 |  
   9. |     3   weight       .         1 |
      +----------------------------------+
```

(2) However, what use is this structure? How are you going to relate `height`, `length` and `weight`? Usually, you would be better off with this (assuming same data as sandbox):

```
  reshape wide value, i(group) j(attr) string 
  renpfix value 
  list, sepby(group)
```

Here we end with variables `group`, `height`, `length` and `weight`. If you still want the `long` structure, that is now achievable with `reshape long`.

Notes:

1. For more on `fillin`, see the help, the manual entry and [this expository note](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0011).
2. `renpfix` in this case zaps prefixes of variable names. The tacit third argument is an empty string, so the prefix `value` is replaced with an empty string, namely removed. In recent versions of Stata (12 up), that is now easy with `rename`.
3. Presumably these data are just a toy example, but I'd be amazed if the `wide` structure were not more useful for your real data too. If there's a reason for the `long` structure, you did not tell us about it. (If you really have panel data, that's a different story, but check out `tsfill`.)

Comment: Thanks!  Easier than I had thought.  Yes, this is a toy example - thanks for also giving the other information about reshape, etc.